# PowerShell Script move computer accounts to different OU

Tags: powershell, vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

This PowerShell Script works for disabling computers, but I cannot get it to moved the computers account to an OU "Disabled". My boss does not want any 3rd party addons to be used to run the script. This is running on Server2008R2, any help would be appreciated.

````
# Specify log file.

    $File = "c:\scripts\OldComputers.log"

# Specify the minimum number of days since the computer has been logged for
# the computer to considered inactive.

    $intDays = 25

# Specify the DN of the OU into which inactive computer objects will be moved.




$TargetOU = "ou=Disabled,dc=helpdesktest,dc=local"

# Bind to target OU.

    $OU = [ADSI]"LDAP://$TargetOU"

    $D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
    $Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
    $Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $Searcher.PageSize = 200
    $Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

# Filter on all non-server computers.

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(!operatingSystem=*server*))"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet") > $Null
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://" + $Domain.distinguishedName


# Write information to log file.


     $Today = Get-Date
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Search for inactive computer accounts"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Start: $Today"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Base of search: $Domain"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Log file: $File"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactive if not logged into in days: $intdays"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactive accounts moved to: $TargetOU"
        Add-Content -Path $File -Value "-------------------------------------------"

    # Initialize totals.


     $Total = 0
        $Inactive = 0
        $NotMoved = 0
        $NotDisabled = 0

        $Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
        ForEach ($Result In $Results)
        {
          $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")
          $PLS = $Result.Properties.Item("pwdLastSet")
          $Total = $Total + 1
       If ($PLS.Count -eq 0)
       {
         $Date = [DateTime]0
       }
      Else
      {

# Interpret 64-bit integer as a date.


      $Date = [DateTime]$PLS.Item(0)
      }

# Convert from .NET ticks to Active Directory Integer8 ticks.
# Also, convert from UTC to local time.


    $PwdLastSet = $Date.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
      If ($PwdLastSet.AddDays($intDays) -lt $Today)
      {

# Computer inactive.

$Inactive = $Inactive + 1
$Computer= [ADSI]"LDAP://$DN"
Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactive: $DN - last login $PwdLastSet"
# Move computer to target OU.
Try
{
  $Computer.psbase.Moveto($OU)
}

Catch
{
  $NotMoved = $NotMoved + 1
  Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Cannot move: $DN"
}
 Try
{

  $Computer.psbase.MoveTo($OU)
}
Catch
{
  $Moved = $Moved + 1
  Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Moved: $DN"
}

# Disable the computer account.

        Try
        {
          $Flag = $Computer.userAccountControl.Value
          $NewFlag = $Flag -bxor 2
          $Computer.userAccountControl = $NewFlag
          $Computer.SetInfo()
        }
        Catch
        {
          $NotDisabled = $NotDisabled + 1
          Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Cannot disable: $DN"
        }
      }
    }

    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Finished: $(Get-Date)"
    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Total computer objects found:  $Total"
    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactive:            $Inactive"
    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactice accounts not moved:  $NotMoved"
    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "Inactive accounts not disabled: $NotDisabled"
    Add-Content -Path $File -Value "-------------------------------------------"

    "Total computer objects found:  $Total"
    "Inactive:                     $Inactive"
    "Inactice accounts not moved:  $NotMoved"
    "Inactive accounts not disabled: $NotDisabled"
    ```]"Done"
````

Comment: But Quest's free Active Directory tools are AWESOME... I live by them.

Comment: What error do you get?